# Hide the app icon and run it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to hide the application icon.
And run the program with dial
Example: *12345#

I can not run a program that has been hidden.

Hide App:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.example.broadcastreciver.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Run MainActivity:

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, Blank.class);
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(appIntent);
```

this is AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Blank"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blank" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Please show your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an alternative way 
And the problem was solved
I've created an intent-filter

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<!-- Here is Launcher -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".IncomingSms" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity

            android:name=".Blank"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blank" >
<intent-filter>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Hide an application icon

```
ComponentName componentToDisable =
                  new ComponentName("com.example.broadcastreciver",
                  "com.example.broadcastreciver.MainActivity");
                getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                  componentToDisable,
                  PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                  PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and for Launch app:

```
String phoneNubmer = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        if (LAUNCHER_NUMBER.equals(phoneNubmer)) {
            setResultData(null);
            Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, Blank.class);
            appIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(appIntent);
        }
```

I hid my MainActivity 
I've created a Intent-filter for the second activity 
To run the application through USSD code (example:*123456#,etc)
I called a second activity (Blank)

Answer (score 4):

If you disable the activity, then it cannot be launched. What you actually want to do is disable or remove the `<intent-filter>` on the activity. Unfortunately manifest intent filters cannot be removed or even inspected (see [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217)).

What you can do is define an [`<activity-alias>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) that has the `<intent-filter>`s, and enable/disable this component instead. When the activity alias is disabled, you will still be able to launch the target activity using an implicit intent, but the app should not appear in the launcher since the disabled component is the one with the intent filter for action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER.

Comment: This works great on pre-API 23. I tested on two different phones running API 23 and the app closes after 12 seconds, but not a full close because my app has a Bluetooth connection that doesn't go down after the app closes. Any workarounds?

Comment: @pigswig This only affects whether an icon appears in the application launcher. It has nothing to do with "closing" an Activity (I'm not even sure what you mean by "close" here).

Comment: "Closing" was not the best choice of words. I have an activity with a checkbox that says "Hide icon". Once the user checks it, after about 12 seconds, the activity goes away as though the home button was pressed. This happens on my Nexus 6 and Moto G3 with both at API 23. Also logcat displays repeatedly: `ActivityManager: Wtf, activity ActivityRecord{d8828a9 u0 com.abc/.MainActivityAlias t6826 f} in proc activity list not using proc ProcessRecord{944a36a 31088:com.abc/u0a170}?!? Using null instead.`